# How can I completely remove the Google Maps Pop-up Balloon?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using Javascript to serve up some KML files but I want to disable the ability to click on the map and display a pop up balloon. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

To block KML file info bubbles from JavaScript:

```
kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://..../myfile.kmz',{
  suppressInfoWindows: true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<gx:balloonVisibility>0</gx:balloonVisibility>
```

See this page for reference:
http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/kmlreference.html#gxballoonvisibility