# Center google map on kml, not location

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geolocation, kml

I have this simple script on a web page, loading a small kml file, but when I add geolocation, it always centers the map on the current location.
And I want to load the map centered on the kml file. User location should only be displayed if he is in the area of the kml, or if he drags the map to the area where he is located.
Accessorily, is there a way to easily refresh the user location on the map with javascript (maps api 3), without re-centering the map ?

```
var map;
function initialize() {
var centre = new google.maps.LatLng(4,4);
var mapOptions = {
zoom: 11,
center: centre
}

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
url: 'http://www.server.com/kmlfile.kml',
preserveViewport: false
});
ctaLayer.setMap(map);

if(navigator.geolocation) {
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
  var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,
                                   position.coords.longitude);

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    map: map,
    position: pos,
    content: 'Location found using HTML5.'
   });

//  map.setCenter(pos);
   }, function() {
  handleNoGeolocation(true);
   });
  }
}

function handleNoGeolocation(errorFlag) {
if (errorFlag) {
var content = 'Error: The Geolocation service failed.';
} else {
var content = 'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.';
}

var options = {
map: map,
position: new google.maps.LatLng(60, 105),
content: content
};

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(options);
map.setCenter(options.position);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

So, here is my latest update, I added the disableAutoPan: true option to infoWindow, as indicated, and to refresh the user position I used **watchPosition** in place of **getCurrentPosition**, together with **setPosition** to move theinfoWindow position :

```
var map;
function initialize() {
  var center_map = new google.maps.LatLng(45,-4);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 11,
    center: centre
  }

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
  url: 'http://www.server.com/kmlfile.kml', preserveViewport: false
}); 
var ctaLayer.setMap(map);
if(navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(function(position) {
    var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
    if(typeof infowindow == "undefined") {
      infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        disableAutoPan: true,
        map: map, position: pos,
        content: 'Your position',
        zIndex: 0 /* not needed */
      });
    }
    else {
      infowindow.setPosition(pos);
    }
  }, function() {
/*handleNoGeolocation(true);*/
/* had to delete this because errors centered the map on North Pole */
  },
  { timeout: 10000, enableHighAccuracy: true  }); /* high accuracy for tests */
  }
}; 

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Apparently it works although I suppose it's quite raw...

Answer (score 1):

When you open the `InfoWindow` it is panning the map to display it.  Set `disableAutoPan` to true in the [`InfoWindowOptions`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#InfoWindowOptions).

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  map: map,
  position: pos,
  content: 'Location found using HTML5.',
  disableAutoPan: true
 });
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/mmx48w6p/3/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;

function initialize() {
  var centre = new google.maps.LatLng(4, 4);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 11,
    center: centre
  }

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
  var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: 'http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/cta.xml',
    preserveViewport: false
  });
  ctaLayer.setMap(map);

  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,
        position.coords.longitude);

      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        disableAutoPan: true,
        map: map,
        position: pos,
        content: 'Location found using HTML5.'

      });

      //  map.setCenter(pos);
    }, function() {
      handleNoGeolocation(true);
    });
  }
}

function handleNoGeolocation(errorFlag) {
  if (errorFlag) {
    var content = 'Error: The Geolocation service failed.';
  } else {
    var content = 'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.';
  }

  var options = {
    map: map,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(60, 105),
    content: content,
    disableAutoPan: true
  };

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(options);
  // map.setCenter(options.position);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, sounds perfect. To refresh the user location I'm trying watchPosition in place of getCurrentPosition, added a 3rd parameter, { timeout: 10000, enableHighAccuracy: true }, looks fine, is that correct ? and sufficient to update user's position ? Can't test with my smartphone yet...

Comment: That is another question.

Comment: Yes a subsidiary question mentioned in my first post... apparently it works but previous infowindows are still displayed (android). Maybe attribute a zIndex...

Comment: related question [How to remove information from info window (on a KmlLayer)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28617292/how-to-remove-information-from-info-window-on-a-kmllayer)

Comment: duplicate of [How can I completely remove the Google Maps Pop-up Balloon?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6766865/how-can-i-completely-remove-the-google-maps-pop-up-balloon/)

Comment: See my edited 1st post where I added your solution to keep the map centered on the kml file area, and I found a solution to display a refreshed user location on the map (I suppose much more tests would be needed to not keep using geolocation if user  is far from the kml area, error handling and messages, etc). Thanks again !